# Simplifying algebraic equation with 2 unknowns

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms, python

I have the following python code:

```
ymin = 1615.72687
ymax = -1607.73011
ec50 = 2.19835099
x,y = symbols('x y')

expression = ((y-ymin)*(ec50+x))+abs(ymax)*x
equation = solve(expression,x)
```

And it spits out the following equation: `[0.5495877475*(-100000.0*y + 161572687.0)/(25000.0*y - 199919.0)]`

`solve` sets `expression` equal to $0$ and solves for `x`. When I tried to do this by hand, I received the following answer: $$x = \frac{(y)(ec50) - (ymin)(ec50)}{\mid{ymax}\mid - y -ymin}$$

Hence, I don't see how that equation translates to what was outputted by Python. Also, my assumption for Python multiplying `y` by $100000.0$ is to compensate for the shift in the other variables. But even taking that into consideration doesn't help me understand the discrepancy between the two equations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution for $x$ has some wrong signs in the denominator. The correct solution is:

$$
x = \frac{ec_{50}(-y+y_{min})}{y - y_{min} + |y_{max}|}
$$

Substituting the numerical values:

$$
\begin{align}
x = \frac{2.19835099\,(-y+1615.72687)}{y - 1615.72687
 + 1607.73011} & = \frac{2.19835099\,(-y+1615.72687)}{y -7.99676}  \\[5px]
 & = \frac{\frac{2.19835099}{4}\,(-100000y+161572687)}{25000 y - 199919}  \\[5px]
\end{align}
$$

The latter matches the Python code.

Answer (score 0):

your by-hand solution is slightly off. It should be
$$x = \frac{y\cdot ec50 - ymin\cdot ec50}{ymin - y -\mid{ymax}\mid}$$.

Taking this into account (and multiplying $y$ by $100000$), the result is correct.

On a side note: The tags you used are way off. This has nothing to do with quadratic forms. And even though it is python code, the relevant thing would be the computer-algebra system you used (probably "sage", or "maxima" or somthing lige that...). Anyway, welcome to stackexchange :)